# Idioms to say If there is something needed to be done, then do it today?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

My friend try to use idioms/parse to express that "If there is something has to be done, then let's do it right now, not postpone to other day."

She was trying to use "One of these days is none of these days", labelled on her product package, trying to be cool :)

But I felt that sounds weird... The parse itself doesn't make sense alone by itself...
Its make sense during conversion like here: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/One+of+these+days+is+none+of+these+days

So is there any other idioms that can be use alone, a parse on the product/poster/shirt itself that sounds cool?

Comment: Well, there's always "Never do today what can be put off until tomorrow."  (Or is that the other way around?)

Comment: If you're looking for a one word answer, essentially any antonym of procrastination would do. Alacrity(promptness in response/cheerful readiness). Anticipate (to deal with beforehand).

Comment: Strike while the iron is hot.

Comment: *Once more unto the breach, dear friends.*

Comment: @HotLicks  I don't really understand... sounds like opposite? Postpone what you can postpone?

Comment: @KingChan He's kidding. Here'e the original ["never put off until tomorrow what you can do today"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/never-put-off-until-tomorrow-what-you-can-do-today)

Comment: @NVZ LOL I see.  I wonder if I can just make the arrangement myself, like "never put off until tomorrow what you SHOULD do today"... Maybe that will not be idioms anymore...?

Answer (score 7):

**It's now or never** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27s+now+or+never)

> something that you say which means that you must do something immediately because you will not get another opportunity
>
> *"As she was leaving I thought, it's now or never. So I just went up to her and asked her out."*

**There's no time like the present.** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There%27s+no+time+like+the+present)

> something that you say in order to show that you think it is a good idea to do something immediately
>
> *"When do you think I should phone Mr Hughes about that job?' 'Well, there's no time like the present.'"*

**Seize the day!** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/seize+the+day)

> to use an opportunity to do something that you want and not to worry about the future.
>
> *"Seize the day, young man. You may never get the chance to embark on such an adventure again."*

<sub>Related: [A list of famous inspirational quotes about procrastination](http://www.keepinspiring.me/procrastination-quotes/).</sub>

Comment: It's a shame they can't use "kal kare so aaj kar," if you get what I mean. I wrote this assuming you'd know hindi.

Comment: @vickyace I know. Kabir. "aaj kare so ab kar"

Comment: Everyone's answer is awesome!  Personally I thinl It's now or never is simple, short (can put on little space) and clean!  Thanks!

Comment: @vickyace Now I just got questioned by my friend, 'It's now or never' sounds like you do it now, or you don't do it.  Doesn't match her expression do not postpone...which if things postponed, you can still do it later

Comment: Or it can be use as you have to behave like it is now or never? Or yu will not do it?

Comment: @KingChan There's a Drake song with lyrics, "better late than never, but never late is better". How about that? :)

Comment: @KingChan "it's now or never" doesn't mean "do it now, or don't do it". It means "you may not get another chance to do it even if you wanted to"

Comment: @NVZ Sorry, my typo, I mean yes, it means "You may not get another chance to do it even if you wanted to".

Comment: @NVZ Right now I just wonder does the idioms have to use only when its in that situation?  Like "Better late than never, but never late is better", is expressing to not be late, even late is better than never done....Because is sounds like totally different from her "If something has to be done, let's get it done today"

Comment: Carpe diem is also an option, the movie Dead Poets Society popularized this expression in the 90s

Answer (score 3):

> Make hay while the sun shines

http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/make-hay-while-the-sun-shines.html

Answer (score 0):

Minutes are worth more than money. Spend them wisely. ~Thomas P. Murphy
[http://www.liveinspiremotivate.com/carpe-diem-quotes]

Answer (score 0):

Procrastination is another term for this activity, the more you procrastinate the more you will develop stress and anxiety over time.

https://www.firstinspire.com/self-improvement/stop-procrastinating-in-2021/

Comment: As for the idiom, how does this answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

This is an idiom that captures the notion of doing things right the first time: 
*A stitch in time saves nine*. It is a [proverb that means](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-stitch-in-time.html) "a timely effort will prevent more work later".

The intent isn't to "stitch time", but rather, that by making a quick stitch to something coming apart now, a lot of time and trouble will be saved later due to the entire thing unraveling and falling apart. Think of a sail.